# Demonstration of Controlability and Observability

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

After I studied my Control Engineering courses some years ago, although I was able to interpret the results obtained after calculating the observability and controllability, I haven't been able to find a demonstration of the equations that are related to both terms.

### The equations [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observability#Observability_matrix)

Controllability matrix
$$
\mathcal  {C} =
\begin{bmatrix}
B & AB & A^{{2}}B &
\cdots & A^{{n-1}}B
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Observability matrix
$$
\mathcal {O}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
C\\CA\\CA^{2}\\\vdots \\CA^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Please add the details of the equations you have in mind. What do you mean by demonstration? Do you mean examples? Do you have specific examples in mind?

Comment: @AJN the equations of the observability and controlability are $\left[C, CA, CA^2,...,CA^n \right]^T$, and $\left[B, BA, BA^2,...,BA^n \right]$ respectively. I don't get to see how does matrixes and their ranks are able to tell us if it is possible to control/observe certain variables and all the other conclusions and uses that can be found.

Comment: IIRC, the equations when derived for *discrete time* systems are easier to understand intuitively. I will see if I can find a good reference or type one up myself. You will need to know the concept of *linearly independent set of vectors* and the concept of *basis* and *spanning of vector spaces*. Are you familiar with those concepts?

Comment: I have learned the equations with the multiplication in the reverse order. $A^k\ B$ etc.

Comment: See if this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability#Discrete_linear_time-invariant_(LTI)_systems) section explains it. The *derivation* and *example* subsections both provide good insight IMO.

Comment: @AJN yeah, I'm familiarized with all of those concepts!!!